# Processing Json Data in number format

Tags: json

How do i handle j son data in number? I am not able to get the last Updated Time into the Data Table.

I am enable to get the data to the data table that are strings but not the number. How should i go about it to solve this? Here are my code and thanks lot.

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "location": "44994f77-e633-4d82-847c-1ccbb01e9ec4",
      "type": "Manager",
      "serialNumber": "FOC1537W1ZY",
      "family": "John",
      "lastUpdateTime": 1476263348659,
      "siblings": null,
      "children": "",
      "hiredate": "2016-04-13 02:56:25",
      "medicalStatus": "clear",
      "age": "55",
    }
 ],
"version": "1.0"
}


  public class Response
    {
        public string location { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string serialNumber { get; set; }
        public string family { get; set; }
        public object lastUpdateTime { get; set; }
        public object siblings { get; set; }
        public string children { get; set; }
        public string hireDate{ get; set; }
        public string age{ get; set; }

    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Response> response { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }
    }



        DataTable dtPromotions = new DataTable();
            dtPromotions.Columns.Add("location", typeof(string));
            dtPromotions.Columns.Add("type", typeof(string));
            dtPromotions.Columns.Add("serialNumber", typeof(string));
            dtPromotions.Columns.Add("family", typeof(string));
            dtPromotions.Columns.Add("lastUpdatedTime", typeof(string));
            dtPromotions.Columns.Add("siblings", typeof(string));
            dtPromotions.Columns.Add("children", typeof(string));
            dtPromotions.Columns.Add("hireDate", typeof(string));
            dtPromotions.Columns.Add("age", typeof(string));





            foreach (var off in hostdata2)
            {
                string off1 = Convert.ToString(off);
                string[] RowData = Regex.Split(off1.Replace
                ("{", "").Replace("}", ""), ",");
                DataRow nr = dtPromotions.NewRow();
                foreach (string rowData in RowData)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int idx = rowData.IndexOf(":");
                        string RowColumns = rowData.Substring
                        (0, idx - 1).Replace("\"", "").Trim();
                        string RowDataString = rowData.Substring
                        (idx + 1).Replace("\"", "");
                        nr[RowColumns] = RowDataString;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ex.Message.ToString();
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                dtPromotions.Rows.Add(nr);
            }



    RadGrid1.DataSource = dtPromotions;
        RadGrid1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your r getting time-stamp value from database. convert it in date time !

Comment: Thanks but i don't access to the database and there is no way i can change it to a date. I am giving an API location and i need to populate to a datatable. How should i covert it to a date given the example above. Thanks a lot

Comment: use data() method !